# Total orderings

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-set-theory, order-theory

[image]

First they need to be in partiel ordning, which only E, H and I fulfill. then every two elements in the set need to be comparable, the relation is then called a total ordering, but how do I figure out if there are comparable?

Comment: For a relation to be a total order, there is a list of requirements that needs to be fulfilled. Surely you have such a list somewhere in your notes or textbook or something. For each of the relations above, you are supposed to either check that all requirements are fulfilled, or point out how one specific requirement fails.

Comment: 1)refxivity(it is reflexive in this case)
2)anti-symmetricity(it is anti-symmetric) 
3)transitivity(it is transitive)
4)comparibility
For it to be called total ordering it needs to fulfill theses requirement, E, H and I fulfill 1,2,3 but how do I check for number 4, have looked everywhere?

Comment: Number 4 means that every pair of elements must be comparable. For instance, you need either $(b, c)$ or $(c, b)$ to be in the relation (because otherwise you can't say which of $b$ and $c$ are largest, i.e. you can't compare them).

Comment: this mean that h and I is correct in the exercise, and e not because it don't have either (b,c) or (c,b) correct?

Comment: That sounds reasonable, yes. Basically, a partial order where any two elements are comparable will be a total order.

Comment: but isn't d also in a total ordering?

Comment: No. Because there you have both $(a, b)$ and $(b, a)$, for instance. That breaks antisymmetry.

Comment: thanks very much, that's was big help :-)

Answer (score 0):

A total order is reflexive, anti-symmetric, transitive, and has the property that every pair of elements is comparable.

Let's look at $E$, $H$, and $I$; the partial orders. Since $E$ has no relation between $a$ and $c$, it cannot be a total order.

Both $H$ and $I$ are total orders, $H$ stating $a < b < c$ and $I$ stating $a < c < b$.